# How to use SetProcessMitigationPolicy with C#

Tags: c#, c++, native, extern

I need to implement the following C++ code into C#.

```
PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY signaturePolicy = { };
signaturePolicy.MicrosoftSignedOnly = true;
SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessSignaturePolicy, &signaturePolicy, sizeof(signaturePolicy));
```

I have already defined the extern and the struct, but i dont know to use the parameters for the function.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetProcessMitigationPolicy(int policy, PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY lpBuffer, int size);

    private struct PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY
    {
        private uint MicrosoftSignedOnly;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetProcessMitigationPolicy(??) // what do do there? how to get the required sizeof?
    }
```

Can anyone explain me how to pass the required parameters in the right way? Thanks.

Comment: Second parameter must be `ref`, use Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY)) to pass the size.

Comment: well, it compiles correctly but doesnt seems to be working, im still able to load any kind of dll into the process